# Unrecognized field "className" , @JsonTypeInfo

Tags: java, jackson

The conversion from json to java object is failing.It failing after updating to jackson version 2.9.7.

```
 @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = 
     JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "className")
 public class DefaultValidator implements Validator {}


  ObjectMapper objectMapper=new ObjectMapper(); 
  objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
  objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNWRAPPED_TYPE_IDENTIFIERS, false);
  objectMapper.setVisibilityChecker(VisibilityChecker.Std.defaultInstance()
            .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
            .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
            .withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE));
  obj = objectMapper.readValue(jsonBody, clazz);`
```

UIRowInput{private DefaultValidator rowCommmonValidator;}

Following is the exception :

> Unrecognized field "@class" (class com.fe.core.validator.DefaultValidator), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ]) at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 3043] (through reference chain: com.ui.request.input.UpdateGraphInputRequest["graphInput"]->com.model.ui.graph.UIGraphInput["nodeInputs"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.model.ui.graph.item.node.UINodeInput["nodeInputs"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.model.ui.graph.item.node.UINodeInput["lineItemInputs"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.model.ui.graph.item.lineItem.UILineItemInput["tabInput"]->com.model.ui.graph.item.lineItem.matrix.UITabInput["rowInputs"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.model.ui.graph.item.lineItem.matrix.UIRowInput["rowCommmonValidator"]->com.fe.core.validator.DefaultValidator["@class"])

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you share what fails? Any logging, output, stacktrace, anything? "It doesn't work" just doesn't cut it.

Comment: PF updated description

Comment: It used to working in with "2.9.2" jackson in java 7 environemnt. After updating to "2.9.7" and java 8 environment this issue is happening.

Comment: the error messages says no properties matched with class properties, try this on class `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`